# MobaXterm captures hotkeys when I am in another program

Tags: hotkeys, mobaxterm

For example, while in Notepad++ when I press ctrl+alt+m, MobaXterm opens a local terminal session.  How can I stop this, please?  I don't want MobaXterm capturing anything in my Windows environment.

This is driving me nuts!

Windows 7 machine.
MobaXterm Personal v10.5

Answer (score 14):

There's no built-in option to disable the pop-up terminal, but you can disable/change the specific hotkey that is interfering:

1. Click Settings --> Keyboard Shortcuts.
2. Select a hotkey to be modified (`Show / hide popup terminal` in your case).
3. Select the "Edit Keyboard Shortcut" drop down box and select a different hotkey or `<none>` to disable.
4. Restart MobaXterm

Comment: I don't see the "Edit Keyboard Shortcut" when I choose the key to be modified

Comment: I just forget to restart it.

Answer (score 0):

When one presses `CTRL`+`ALT`+`M` MobaXterm's default hotkey is "Show/hide popup terminal".

In order to change that, in the top bar, press `Settings` > `Keyboard shortcuts`

[image]

A popup where one can edit the Hotkeys will appear. The last one "Show / hide popup terminal" is the one you are looking for.

[image]

In the drop-down "Edit keyboard shortcut" select None and that wont bother you again

[image]